# Google Test: Action that accepts a vector as a parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest

I have a GoogleTest Action defined below.

```
ACTION_P5(ReadAction, aa, bb, cc, dd, ee) {

    shared_ptr<DataResponse> response = move(DataResponse::Create());

    response->DataV3.a = aa;
    response->DataV3.b = bb;
    response->DataV3.c = cc;
    response->DataV3.d = dd;
    response->DataV3.e = ee;

    return response;
}
```

This function gets called when a message is sent to an interface. The first four values in the structure `response` (i.e `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) are numbers. However the fifth one is a `vector` of `uint8_t`.

Would the above assignment work correctly ? Am I missing something. Since Action is macro drive how is type safety ensured.

Comment: I can't find anything about 'ACTION_Px' on google test. Can you give me a hint what it is?

Comment: @Klaus It's part of GMock specification. Here it's a user-defined parameterized action, which takes 5 arguments: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.8.0/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#writing-new-parameterized-actions-quickly

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that `response->DataV3.e` and the action parameter `ee` are type of `vector<uint8_t>`?

If so, the assignment works correctly. It will work in your desired way(deep-copied by the nature of `vector`'s assignment operator).

One concern is that *gmock* internally builds some data structures for the actions internally which causes copy constructions for a few times. It could be a huge overhead for large vectors. If you would like to avoid those unwanted copies, you may need to wrap with reference(e.g. using `std::ref`) or pass it as pointer. Then just copy once when you really assign it.